# Rewrite redux-orm reducer with redux-toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-orm, redux-toolkit

## Issue (tl;dr)

How can we create a [custom redux-orm reducer](https://redux-orm.github.io/redux-orm/advanced/custom-reducer#updating-the-store-state) with [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org)'s [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#createslice)?

Is there a simpler, recommended, more elegant or just *other* solution than the attempt provided in this question?

## Details

The example of a [custom redux-orm reducer](https://redux-orm.github.io/redux-orm/advanced/custom-reducer#updating-the-store-state) looks as follows (simplified):

```js
function ormReducer(dbState, action) {
    const session = orm.session(dbState);
    const { Book } = session;

    switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_BOOK':
        Book.create(action.payload);
        break;
    case 'REMOVE_AUTHOR_FROM_BOOK':
        Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).authors.remove(action.payload.authorId);
        break;
    case 'ASSIGN_PUBLISHER':
        Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).publisherId = action.payload.publisherId;
        break;
    }

    return session.state;
}
```

It's possible to simplify reducers with the [`createSlice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#createslice) function of [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) (based on the redux-toolkit [usage-guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#exporting-and-using-slices)):

```js
const ormSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'orm',
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    createBook(state, action) {},
    removeAuthorFromBook(state, action) {},
    assignPublisher(state, action) {}
  }
})
const { actions, reducer } = ormSlice
export const { createBook, removeAuthorsFromBook, assignPublisher } = actions
export default reducer
```

However, at the beginning of redux-orm reducer we need to create a session

```js
const session = orm.session(dbState);
```

then we do our redux-orm reducer magic, and at the end we need to return the state

```js
return session.state;
```

So we miss something like `beforeEachReducer` and `afterEachReducer` methods in the `createSlice` to add this functionality.

## Solution (attempt)

We created a `withSession` higher-order function that creates the session and returns the new state.

```js
const withSession = reducer => (state, action) => {
  const session = orm.session(state);
  reducer(session, action);
  return session.state;
}
```

We need to wrap every reducer logic in this `withSession`.

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import orm from './models/orm'; // defined elsewhere
// also define or import withSession here

const ormSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'orm',
  initialState: orm.session().state, // we need to provide the initial state
  reducers: {
    createBook: withSession((session, action) => {
      session.Book.create(action.payload);
    }),
    removeAuthorFromBook: withSession((session, action) => {
      session.Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).authors.remove(action.payload.authorId);
    }),
    assignPublisher: withSession((session, action) => {
      session.Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).publisherId = action.payload.publisherId;
    }),
  }
})

const { actions, reducer } = ormSlice
export const { createBook, removeAuthorsFromBook, assignPublisher } = actions
export default reducer
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a fascinating question for me, because [I created Redux Toolkit](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2019/10/redux-starter-kit-1.0/), and I wrote extensively about using Redux-ORM in [my "Practical Redux" tutorial series](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/series/practical-redux/).

Off the top of my head, I'd have to say your `withSession()` wrapper looks like the best approach for now.

At the same time, I'm not sure that using Redux-ORM and `createSlice()` together really gets you a lot of benefit.  You're not making use of Immer's immutable update capabilities inside, since Redux-ORM is handling updates within the models.  The only real benefit in this case is generating the action creators and action types.

You might be better off just calling `createAction()` separately, and using the original reducer form with the generated action types in the switch statement:

```js
export const createBook = createAction("books/create");
export const removeAuthorFromBook = createAction("books/removeAuthor");
export const assignPublisher = createAction("books/assignPublisher");

export default function ormReducer(dbState, action) {
    const session = orm.session(dbState);
    const { Book } = session;

    switch (action.type) {
    case createBook.type:
        Book.create(action.payload);
        break;
    case removeAuthorFromBook.type:
        Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).authors.remove(action.payload.authorId);
        break;
    case assignPublisher.type:
        Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).publisherId = action.payload.publisherId;
        break;
    }

    return session.state;
}
```

I see what you're saying about adding some kind of "before/after" handlers, but that would add too much complexity.  RTK is intended to handle the 80% use case, and the TS types for `createSlice` are already incredibly complicated.  Adding any more complexity here would be bad.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this question looking to combine the benefits of [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)
and [redux-orm](https://redux-orm.github.io/redux-orm/). I was able to come up with a solution I've been pretty happy
with so far. Here is what my redux-orm model looks like:

```js
class Book extends Model {

    static modelName = 'Book';

    // Declare your related fields.
    static fields = {
        id: attr(), // non-relational field for any value; optional but highly recommended
        name: attr(),
        // foreign key field
        publisherId: fk({
            to: 'Publisher',
            as: 'publisher',
            relatedName: 'books',
        }),
        authors: many('Author', 'books'),
    };

    static slice = createSlice({
      name: 'BookSlice',
      // The "state" (Book) is coming from the redux-orm reducer, and so will
      // never be undefined; therefore, `initialState` is not needed.
      initialState: undefined,
      reducers: {
        createBook(Book, action) {
            Book.create(action.payload);
        },
        removeAuthorFromBook(Book, action) {
            Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).authors.remove(action.payload.authorId);
        },
        assignPublisher(Book, action) {
            Book.withId(action.payload.bookId).publisherId = action.payload.publisherId;
        }
      }
    });

    toString() {
        return `Book: ${this.name}`;
    }
    // Declare any static or instance methods you need.

}

export default Book;
export const { createBook, removeAuthorFromBook, assignPublisher } = Book.slice.actions;
```

The redux-toolkit slice is created as a static property on the class, and then
the model and its actions are exported in a manner similar to Ducks
(ORMDucks??).

The only other modification to make is to define a custom updater for
redux-orm's reducer:

```js
const ormReducer = createReducer(orm, function (session, action) {
    session.sessionBoundModels.forEach(modelClass => {
        if (typeof modelClass.slice.reducer === 'function') {
            modelClass.slice.reducer(modelClass, action, session);
        }
    });
});
```

See a more complete example here:
https://gist.github.com/JoshuaCWebDeveloper/25a302ec891acb6c4992fe137736160f

#### Some Notes

- @markerikson makes a good point about some of the features of redux-toolkit
  not being used since redux-orm is managing the state. For me, the two
  greatest benefits of using this method are not having to wrangle a whole
  bunch of action creators and not having to contend with awful `switch`
  statements :D.
- I am using the stage 3 class fields and static class features proposals. (See
  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties). To make
  this ES6 compatible, you can easily refactor the model class to define its
  static props using the current syntax (i.e. `Book.modelName = 'Book';`).
- If you decide to mix models like the one above with models that don't define
  a `slice`, then you'll need to tweak the logic in the `createReducer` updater
  slightly.

For a real world example, see how I use the model in my project here: 
https://github.com/vallerance/react-orcus/blob/70a389000b6cb4a00793b723a25cac52f6da519b/src/redux/models/OrcusApp.js.
This project is still in the early stages. The largest question in my mind is
how well this method will scale; however, I am optimistic that it will continue
to provide numerous benefits as my project matures.

Comment: Huh, that's pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [normalized-reducer](https://github.com/brietsparks/normalized-reducer). It's a higher-order-reducer that takes a schema describing the relationships, and returns a reducer, action, and selectors that write/read according to the relationships.

It also integrates easily with Normalizr and Redux Toolkit.