# Setting redux toolkit `initialState` based on passed `data-` attribute at runtime

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React app that can be embedded several times on a single html page. Each time the html tag can come with a different `data-*` attribute that is used for initialisation of the app:

```html
<div class="my-app" data-my-config="SOME_ENCODED_JSON_PROPERTIES" />
```

Depending on the passed `SOME_ENCODED_JSON_PROPERTIES` the app's redux store is to be initilized with a different `initialState`. Reading the docs and examples on [initialState](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#initialstate), the initialState is always set from some static `const` variables - how can it be set at "runtime" passed on the initial `data-my-config` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples can only show basics - it's important to extrapolate what's *possible* based on those.

In this case, the key is that you have to have the data available, in scope, at the time that you call `createSlice()`.  How you get that value and where it comes from is up to you.

If that's not feasible given your architecture, then you can always provide a placeholder initial state, and then either:

- Override that value by providing a `preloadedState` argument to `configureStore` that contains data for this slice
- Define an reducer in the slice that replaces its state with the action payload, and dispatch that action after the initial store is created

Comment: Thanks for answering, sorry if I sounded offensive regarding the examples, I rather just wanted to make clear that I already searched the web and docs quite a bit. Yeah, the data is not in scope when calling `createSlice`, that's the problem. Will look into `preloadedState`...

Anyway, by accident I came across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60999058/load-initialstate-dynamically-with-createslice-in-redux-toolkit just now which seems to give another 3rd option. Though, it sounds more of a workaround.

Comment: So, going the `preloadedState` path does not seem to work bc `configureStore` also needs to run at initialisation (but I need it to run at  DOMContentLoaded, so data is available) due to TypeScript and https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/651#issuecomment-658193473 Well, so in the end only the 2nd option with creating "initial reducers" for all slices seem to be the only option if I am correct :-/